# ReactJS returning saved response and passing to different component

Tags: reactjs, express, components

Our project is in REACT and backend is in Express.

I am not able to return Inserted Id of the parent table to my component and pass it to other component which needs Parent ID to render a Add Child button (which passes parent id in child record)

Each parent record has additional "Add Floorplan" button which adds record in its child table. (check Image 1)

So, while rendering all the parent table rows, I am checking if "ID" exists then show "Add" button for that row. I cannot show “Add Floorplan” button at the time of rendering as its parent record wont be there and not be able to pass “parent id” which is foreign key in child table.

Check code below to render Add Floorplans (child table record) button :

```
class FloorPlanButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.props.dependentValues.id ? (
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              this.props.addFloorPlanButton(this.props.dependentValues.id)
            }
          >
            Add Floorplans
          </button>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to render "Add Child" button, when user click "Add Row (parent - check top right of Image 1)" & save that record. It saves record in parent table but not able to show Add Floorplan button as while rendering button wasn’t there. (check Image 2)

Check code below which saves parent table record :

```
let response = await AboutService.insertTableData(url, {data: data});
```

Both codes are in different Component and files.

Please see below work flow to explain this situation of files/components & data flow:

1. There is a file, “home.js” which renders Content Management component and passes all the data to show (parent table)
2. Content Management Component :

   - a.    Renders all the parent rows with “Add Row” button to add new Parent Row
   - b.    Each parent row has a button called “Add Floorplan” (child table)
3. Clicking Add Row button passes all the entered data (of parent table) to main file “home.js”
4. Home.js file has function “insertData” to communicate to Express which saves data in proper table and return response.
5. Problem : I am not able to find a way to pass this updated data (old records+ new record) to Content Management Component and show “Add Floorplan” button for new record without re-rendering it.

Please help me to render "Add Floorplan" button when parent record(s) is/are saved without re-rendering or refreshing the panel.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once the data is inserted, you may call your get data promise ( hope it is in a function, so that can be easily called) again, which is possibly updating your state with the latest records.

In the child component you may use a lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` which will set the state of the child component and apply the changes accordingly.

Best article to play with React Life cycle:-
http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

Let react make his job tho. I am assuming that u are storing current rows inside parent state. So when the response arrives just add the record to the state (immutably, so react can infer something changed). And then in next render pass new props to child. React with its reconciliation will do the dirty work for u. Solve performance problems when its necessary. Readability first.